# How to make Android Facebook "Like" toggle button

Tags: android, xml

How to make this type of toggle button? I have tried search google on toggle button, it give me something not I want. If possible I'd like to use the vector asset icon from android studio. But I don't know how to create a border icon like the "Like" button below.

[image: Toggle Button]

Comment: this will help you https://www.flaticon.com/search?word=facebook%20like

Comment: use drawables ?

Comment: @NileshRathod I just tested and load the a few icons to android studio, seems like works pretty well. thank you so much

Comment: @Rick ,most welcome happy to help you

Comment: @Rick From `flaticon.com/search?word=facebook%20like` website, download the required icon in svg format. Then use http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ to convert the svg to xml, then open android studio, create a new drawable xml file, copy paste the xml code. And cheers you got a scalable vector. (y)

Comment: @iamgopal another great answer, thank you everyone!!

Comment: @Rick I have posted the same with more details, please upvote and accept, keep rocking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [flaticon.com/search?word=facebook%20like](http://flaticon.com/search?word=facebook%20like) website, download the required icon in svg format. Then use [inloop.github.io/svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android) to convert the svg to xml, then open android studio, create a new drawable xml file, copy paste the xml code. And cheers you got a scalable vector.

You can change the color of icon, size etc from that drawable file.

Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

copy paste in **drawable / like.xml** and use it wherever you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="155.123"
android:viewportHeight="155.123"
android:width="40dp"
android:height="40dp">
<path
    android:pathData="M150.669 84.068c7.858 -7.823 5.43 -23.647 -8.181 
    -23.647l-35.813 0.024c1.36 -7.584 3.33 -20.156 3.252 -21.343 -0.752                         
    -11.242 -7.918 -24.924 -8.228 -25.484 -1.307 -2.434 -7.906 -5.734 
    -14.547 -4.32 -8.586 1.838 -9.463 7.315 -9.428 8.825 0 0 0.37 14.983 
     0.406 18.981 -4.105 9.016 -18.259 32.71 -22.549 34.536 -1.026 -0.621 
    -2.19 -0.955 -3.401 -0.955l-45.246 0C3.091 70.685 0 73.793 0 
     77.618l0.006 62.533c0.269 3.371 3.133 6.015 6.516 6.015l40.64 0c3.604 0 
     6.534 -2.93 6.534 -6.534l0 -2.076c0 0 1.51 -0.113 2.196 0.328 2.613 
     1.659 5.842 3.747 10.054 3.747l60.647 0c22.674 0 20.24 -20.126 18.169 
    -22.871 3.831 -4.171 6.2 -11.528 2.966 -17.34 2.482 -2.631 6.85 -9.863 
     2.941 -17.352zm-104.903 55.552l-39.256 0 0 -62.408 39.256 0 0 
     62.408zm94.324 -56.089l-0.37 1.545c10.448 2.971 4.887 15.013 -2.608 
     15.794l-0.37 1.545c10.018 2.548 5.239 14.947 -2.608 15.794l-0.37 
     1.539c8.181 1.343 6.2 15.305 -6.194 15.305l-61.686 0.024c-4.356 0 
    -8.324 -4.964 -11.528 -4.964l-2.796 0 0 -48.038c3.485 -2.16 7.769 -4.964 
    10.15 -6.987 4.499 -3.837 22.913 -33.593 22.913 -37.317 0 -3.724 -0.406 
   -19.834 -0.406 -19.834 0 0 3.61 -4.654 11.671 -1.259 0 0 6.784 12.721 
    7.476 22.859 0 0 -3.055 20.884 -4.696 27.436l42.765 0c10.507 0.012 8.502 
    15.013 -1.343 16.558z"
    android:fillColor="#666C75" />
```

**how to use?**

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/like" />
```